# Gluing two smooth functions f and g

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on some analysis exercises and I found this problem, which I could use some help on.

Show that:

For two smooth functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ with $a<b$, there exist smooth functions $h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that:

$h(x)\begin{cases} 
      =f(x) & x\leq a \\
      =g(x) & x\geq b \\ 
   \end{cases}$

So, I suppose, since it is given that $f$ and $g$ are smooth, $h$ should be smooth on intervals:

$(-\infty,a)$ and $(b, \infty)$

But, I'm having trouble understanding how the interval $(a,b)$ affects smoothness of $h$ and how to prove smoothness of $h$ without really knowing anything about $(a,b)$.

Thank you for your help, this is one of the first problems I have worked on involving smoothness, so perhaps I misunderstood some of the theory.

Comment: Can you prove there is a smooth $\phi$ that is $0$ on $(-\infty,a]$ and $1$ on $[b,\infty)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is, that you can construct such a function $h$. But the construction is maybe ugly. Further, you do not need the explicit formula for $h$. But to give you an idea:

Consider the smooth function $\arctan$, which goes to $\pm\frac{\pi}2$ for $x\to \pm\infty$. By rescaling, you can get a function $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that
$\phi(t)=0$ for $t<a$ and $\phi(t)=1$ for $t>b$. Now we construct
$$
h(x)=\phi(b-x+a)f(x)+\phi(x)g(x).
$$
You can check that $h$ is smooth as composition of smooth functions and if $x\leq a$, we get $\phi(x)=0$ and $b-x+a\geq b$ hence $\phi(b-x+a)=1$ and $h(x)=f(x)$. Analogous we get $h(x)=g(x)$ for $x\geq b$.

But this is just one model. Naturally, there are infinitely many smooth functions such as $h$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
You can start finding a smooth function $f_1$ such that
$f_1(x) = f(x)$ for $x \leq a$ and $f_1(x) = 0$ for $x\geq b$.

Similarly, you can construct a smooth function $g_1$ such that
$g_1(x) = g(x)$ for $x\geq b$ and $g_1(x) = 0$ for $x\leq a$.

Finally, let $h = f_1 + g_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although this is helpful I'm still confused by how interval $(a,b)$ affects smoothness of $h$. What happens if $h$ is undefined on $(a,b)$? Wouldn't that mean that $h$ is not smooth, since it wouldn't be continuously differentiable?

Comment: Your function $h$ is smooth in $\mathbb{R}$. Simply, no request is done on its values on the interval $(a,b)$.